# TFS Build Agent Stopped Running

Tags: tfs, build, build-agent

The other evening we attempted to migrate our database to a different server. This ended up getting reversed and everything is now back up and running as expected except for the Builds.

I have removed/re-installed the build agent on the server and all is seemingly running okay.

Agent is online:

[image: Agent Pool]

Services are running:

[image: Running Services]

Roles have been set up:

[image: Roles Setup]

Any ideas why this still isn't running our builds, it just sits there with

> Waiting for available agent

Comment: Apologies, completely forgot about this, I will add an answer that solved the issue for myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking all of PatrickLu-MSFT points, we finally figured out that it was because the configuration was trying to point to 2 different db locations, running

> TFSConfig RemapDBs

to the new db location and removing the old db location configuration solved the issue for us.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple possibilities which may cause this kind of issue. Please try below items to narrow down the issue:

1. Check the build definition requirements ([Demands section](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/options#demands)) and the agent offering. Make sure it has the required capabilities installed on the agent machine.

   When a build is queued, the system **sends the job only to agents that have the capabilities demanded by the build definition**.
2. Check if  **Team Foundation Administration Console** the property of **"Notification URL"** was with **invalid value** of not existed server. Change to an available server if so.
3. Make sure the account that the agent is run under is in the "**Agent Pool Service Account**" role.
4. Try to change a domain account which is a member of the **Build Agent Service Accounts** group and belongs to "Agent Pool Service Account" role, to see whether the agent would work or not.
5. Check build agent machine if it's out of space or not, try with another build agent
6. Restart the whole TFS server and check if this do the trick. Need
   some time to wait.